# Rotate the Quote Bubble shape in Keynote for macOS

Tags: macos, keynote

The Keynote app for macOS offers a couple of its basic shapes for [thought-bubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_balloon) (speech-balloon), one is oval, the other rectangular.

[image: examples of each kind of thought-bubble shape, oval and rectangular]

Notice that both point to the left.

➥ How to make them point in other directions, up, down, or to the right?

When I try flipping them or rotating them (hold down Command while dragging a corner), the text flips or rotates as well. I want the text in regular orientation, just the pointy triangular tip should be moved to top/bottom/right.

Answer (score 1):

With the thought-bubble shape select, you just drag the green position handle on the tip of the callout triangle (for lack of a better term) with the mouse to the position of your liking.

Please see image below.

[image: Keynote quote bubble callout handle]